# Getting the caret/cursor position and keeping it at a specific spot

Tags: c#, position, caret, autofill

I'm currently in a .NET4 Windows Forms Application.

I'm trying to make something like intellisense, but very very basic.

Lets say the user is focusing a `RichTextBox`, and typing something like:
`Search`. After this specific phrase I want it to 'auto fill' like so: `Search ""` and place the caret in between the " ".

That way when the user keeps typing the caret stays in between the  " " like this:

`Search "[usertypinghere][caretposition]"`

I'm not sure how to get the current position of the caret, let alone how to keep it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `SelectionStart` The joy is it's part of [TextBoxBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) so you can have it in `TextBox`, `RichTextBox`, `MaskedTextBox`, or even other's custom derivative. You'll want to subscribe for `TextChanged` event to watch for "Search", then set the `SelectionStart` there after autofill, then subscribe for `SelectionChangedEvent` for keeping the `SelectionStart` from veering off.

Oh, and if you got several keywords, you'll want to combine those keyword in sort of `Dictionary` of `Tuples` to generalize the methods.

EDIT
My test code. No flicker, no overriding controls. Just plain event subscriber

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text == "Search")
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "Search \"\"";
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength - 1;
        }

    }

    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("Search \"") && richTextBox1.Text.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectionStart > richTextBox1.TextLength - 1)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength - 1;
            }
            if (richTextBox1.SelectionStart <= "Search \"".Length)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = "Search\"".Length+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I'm willing to use it for. Thanks!